# Стек страничного интерфейса WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, usercontrol, стек

Вот что мне хочется реализовать (подобное), только для кнопки "назад", где вместо ссылок на сайт - ссылки на UserControl. Желательно ещё и с выходными параметрами.
[https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/javascript-history-object#:~:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83%20%22%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4,%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0%20(%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8)](https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/javascript-history-object#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83%20%22%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4,%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0%20(%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8))

Ломаю голову который день и не могу придумать, как правильнее организовать стек для страничного интерфейса. Но мне хочется сделать так, чтобы к ContentPresenter с помощью Binding можно было привязать свойство, которое реализует INPC и стек, в котором хранятся ТИПЫ предыдущих UserControl-ов, а не их объектов, т.к. иначе список экземпляров будет засорять ОЗУ. И при "открытии" нового UC добавлять в стек его тип данных, а при закрытии удалять последний тип из стека и присваивать главному свойству созданный новый экземпляр с предыдущим типом данных в стеке (типо "return new SomeType"). Возможно ли сделать такой стек? Думаю, что такое возможно с помощью делегатов, но для этого на каждой ViewModel я должна прописывать одну и ту же логику. Хотелось бы всё это автоматизировать, если такое вообще возможно. Слышала про тип данных Type, но как создать новый объект с его помощью - не знаю.

////
Может стоит создать класс, в котором будет описан и метод, и стек с типами данных? Осталось только понять, как возвращать или создавать новый объект с типом данных, полученного из стека. Что-то по типу этого... Не знаю.

```
class StackUC:INPC
{
private UserControl Uc;
public UserControl UC {get{return Uc;} set{Uc = value; OnPropertyChanged();}}
private Stack<Type> Stc = new Stack<Type>;

public Open(Type T)
{
UC = new T;
Stc.Add(T);
}

public Close()
{
Stc.Pop()
UC = new Stc.Peek();
}
}
```

////
Ещё появилась идея создать родительский класс, от которого будут наследоваться методы "открытия" и "закрытия" UC.

Comment: Так, а зачем стек? Если вам надо забыть старые данные, то так их и забывайте, не используйте или `=null`, зачем вам что-то и где-то хранить я не пойму? Я ведь правильно понимаю, что вы хотите `CurrentContent = ЗадатьНовыйКонтентСТипом<тип>()`?

Comment: EvgeniyZ, нужно запоминать порядок предыдущих UserControl-ов. Как, например Вконтакте - открывается меню "Сервисы", в котором можно открыть страницу "Группы" и так далее. А при выходе из какой-нибудь группы отображается предыдущая страница. Только Вконтакте происходит наложение, а мне не хочется засорять память и просто запомнить порядок.

Comment: Контролы, это всякие `TextBox`, `ListBox` и так далее, о каком порядке идет речь?

Comment: EvgeniyZ, речь идёт о UserControl.

Comment: Ну, я о нем и говорю, это представление (XAML), который отображает и обрабатывает UI, так о каком порядке идет речь?

Comment: EvgeniyZ, например, из одной страницы в ContentPresenter я могу отобразить другую, и мне нужно запоминать в стек предыдущую страницу, чтобы при закрытии (кнопка "назад") открывалась предыдущая.

Comment: Ок, а почему вы вообще работаете с UC, когда должны работать с простыми классами, которые будут лишь содержать в себе важную информацию страницы?

Comment: Немного не поняла. Каждая страница имеет разный интерфейс и ViewModel. Например, у меня есть список групп, я открываю определённую группу. Мне открывается её страница. Предыдущий UC для просмотра группы уже не нужен, но при закрытии страницы группы, мне нужно опять отобразить страницу списка групп.

Comment: Смотрите, есть 3 слоя: 1. Model - это данные (запрос на сервер, в базу, чтение файлов с диска и т.д.). 2. View - это весь UI, то есть тот слой, который видит пользователь. Задача этого слоя, отобразить данные и взаимодействовать с пользователем. 3. ViewModel - это некий средний слой, который берет данные из M слоя и делает нужные свойства для V слоя. V слой должен быть независимым от чего либо, он не должен знать, что есть в других слоях и о нем нечего не должны знать другие слои, он лишь знает, что ему надо отобразить данные с некого абстрактного свойства с именем X, не более.

Comment: UserControl - это View слой, а значит и знать о нем вы совершенно нечего не должны. Так почему вы вдруг хотите сделать `UC = new T; Stc.Add(T);`? Вы ведь явно через код пытаетесь создать View слой и впихнуть его в некий "Стек", когда должны создавать VM слой и пихать его уже куда угодно.

Comment: Потому что этот UserControl описывает страницу подобно окну, т.е. на каждый UserControl своя ViewModel.

Comment: Ну, дело, конечно, ваше, но это нарушение, причем очень серьезное. Вы должны разрабатывать приложение так, будто у вас нету вовсе UI, вы работаете с классами, коллекциями и так далее, будто это простой консольный проект. А UI - это приятный бонус, который вы можете потом без труда прицепить, указаниям у него простого `DataContext`.

Comment: Мне просто не хочется засорять память предыдущими объектами. Хотя, может это и не так серьёзно, как мне оно кажется.

Comment: В C# очень хороший сборщик мусора и если объект не используется, то и память не будет расти, его попросту удалит сборщик самостоятельно. Также в WPF есть виртуализация (если вы ее не нарушили), которая рендерит только те объекты, которые видны пользователю. Да и если думать про оптимизацию, то подумайте, что больше занимает места, класс, который содержит в себе, например одно текстовое свойство (`class Test { public string Test{get;} }`) или контрол, который содержит в себе кучи других свойств (размер, цвет, позиция и т.д..)? Это одна из причин, почему не работают с контролами напрямую.

Comment: Ну как я поняла, то в UC на кнопку "открытия" какого-либо элемента можно просто сделать присваивание нового UC к свойству, привязанному к ContentPresenter. Тогда в каждом UC нужно объявить конструктор, во входном значении которого хранить ссылку на тип UC, вызвавшего открытие.

Comment: Возьмите библиотеку призм, очень удобно там такое делать.

Comment: А готовый велосипед `Frame` + `Page` почему не подходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я смогла наконец реализовать это.

Для реализации такой возможности я создала класс ***HistoryInterface***, содержащий основную логику, и дополнительный ***HistoryUC***, который является представлением записи для стека (хранит информацию, необходимую для создания UserControl-a).

Далее код с комментариями:

```
public static class HistoryInterface
{
    static object mframe;//Объект, который хранит нужный UserControl
    public static object Mframe { get { return mframe; } set { mframe = value; NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(); } }//Свойство, 
                                                                            //которое хранит и отображает текущий UserControl
    static Stack<HistoryUC> History = new Stack<HistoryUC>();//Стек истории UserControl-ов
    public static void AddUC(object frame, object[] param = null)//Метод добавления UC в History. Выполняется в конструкторе необходимого UC
    {
        Mframe = frame;//Изменение отображаемого UC
        History.Push(new HistoryUC(frame.GetType(), param));//Добавление "конфигурации" объекта в стек
    }

    public static void DropUC()//Метод "закрытия" UC. Может выполняться, например, при нажатии кнопки "назад"
    {
        History.Pop();//Удаляем последний объект
        HistoryUC obj = History.Peek();//Выбираем последнюю "конфигурацию" объекта
        Mframe = obj.ret();//Выполняем создание UC
    }
    //Реализация INPC для статических свойств в статическом классе
    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
    private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (StaticPropertyChanged != null)
        {
            StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}


public class HistoryUC //Класс, который описывает элемент стека History.
                       //Хранит тип данных и параметры, необходимые для создания экземпляра указанного типа
{
    Type type;
    object[] args;//Переменная, которая хранит необходимые аргументы
    public HistoryUC(Type uc, object[] arg)//конструктор нового экземпляра
    {
        args = arg;//Присваиваем входные аргументы
        type = uc;//Присваиваем тип данных
    }

    public object ret()//Метод, который возвращает новый экземпляр UC
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
    }
}
```

Теперь, в конструкторах UserControl-ов, которые необходимо запоминать в стек, нужно прописывать метод `HistoryInterface.AddUC()` (причём, если параметров нет, их можно не указывать). И, таким образом, при создании нового экземпляра UserControl-a будет создаваться запись в стек.
А при закрытии текущего userControl-a, на кнопку выхода нужно создать обработчик (или команду), в которой прописывается метод `HistoryInterface.DropUC()`

Свойство MFrame хранит текущий UserControl и привязан к `ContentPresenter`, который находится в окне. Т.к. это свойство изменяемое, пришлось реализовать а-ля интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged для статического класса.